# Formula for calculating the total interest payable over the life of a loan with linear redemption scheme

Tags: summation, finance

I am trying to calculate the lifetime interest paid on a loan with a linear redemption scheme. I know that I can enter it into a spreadsheet and take the sum of the interest, but is there a formula to calculate such a value when you know the balance, duration, monthly redemption and the interest rate? I've done a lot of searching, but end op mostly at annuity calculations or loans with a fixed repayment.

P: Principal (amount) of loan

R: The monthly redemption on the loan

T: The term of the loan (i.e. the number of repayments)

r: The annual interest rate

If for example the Principal is $120.000$, the monthly redemption $1.000$, the term 120 months and the nominal yearly interest is $3%$ paid monthly at the end of each month.

Then the interest is $120.000*(0,03/12)$ the first month. The second month it's $(120.000-1000)*(0,03/12)$. The third it's $(120.000-2*1000)*(0,03/12)$ and so on.

What would be the formula to sum this whole series up? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearly the total principal payments are $120000$.

The total interest payments are:
\begin{align*}
120000 &\times \frac{0.03}{12} + (120000-1000) \times \frac{0.03}{12}+(120000-2000)\times \frac{0.03}{12}+\cdots + 1000 \times \frac{0.03}{12}\\
&= \frac{0.03}{12}\times\left(\sum_{k=1}^{120} 1000\times k\right)\\
&= \frac{0.03}{12}\times 1000 \times \sum_{k=1}^{120}k \\
&= \frac{0.03}{12} \times 1000\times \frac{120\times 121}{2} \\
&= 18150.
\end{align*}

---

Edit 1: In general, the total interest payments will be:
$$\frac{r}{12}\sum_{k=1}^T Rk = \frac{r}{12}R\frac{T(T+1)}{2}= \frac{rP(T+1)}{24}$$
(since $P=RT$ - this assumes the loan is repaid in full after $T$ terms).

---

Edit 2: If the loan is not paid in full after $T$ terms (i.e., $RT<P$), then the interest in the first $T$ terms is:

\begin{align*}
\frac{r}{12}&\left(P + (P-R) + (P-2R) + \cdots + (P-(T-1)R)\right)\\
&=\frac{r}{12} \sum_{k=0}^{T-1}(P-Rk)\\
&= \frac{r}{12}\left(\sum_{k=0}^{T-1} P  - R \sum_{k=0}^{T-1}k \right)\\
&= \frac{r}{12}\left(TP - R \frac{(T-1)T}{2}\right)\\
&= \frac{rT}{12} \left(P- \frac{R(T-1)}{2}\right).
\end{align*}

You can check that when $RT=P$, this expression coincides with the original answer.

Comment: Awesome, thank you kindly for your prompt response

Comment: @Matthijs, it would be nice if you indicate that this is an answer for your question.

Comment: I definitely did that but it said that it counted the upvote, but not show it because I am new (low reputation)

Comment: @Matthijs There should be a "check mark" that is separate from the upvote button.

Comment: Thanks. Did not know that. If the loan is not fully repaid at the end, then this formula does not seem to work, for example when the redemption is 500 a month. Is it also possible to calculate the total interest then?

Comment: I’m not sure what you mean. You want to calculate the total interest after $120$ months when only $500$ per month is paid?

Comment: Yes exactly, so the residual amount is 60.000. Your formula helped me although I don't quite understand it properly. I now calculate it like this: ((Principal + (Principal-redemption*(Term-1)))/2)*(interest/12). Which in this example is ((120.000 + (120.000-1.000*(120-1)))/2)*(3/12)

Comment: Not quite... what you've written is just the interest in the first term and the last term. I will edit my answer to include what happens when the loan is not repaid in full.

Comment: Sorry I see the $1/2$ in your comment now. So you have calculated the average interest paid per term, but you need to multiply by the number of terms (see the $T$ in my last edit).

Comment: You're right, I forgat to multiply with the number of terms. Thanks again for all your help.